# Possible to add "Date Added" column to Apache directory listing?

Tags: apache

In the Apache directory listing https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options (using the index option) is it possible to add a "Date Added" column? Or change the Last Modified column to read from the file/directory's date added field instead? Something to that affect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. There's no "Date Created" option in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html

You would have to create your own custom indexes via a server-side script to extract that kind of information.